# How to make number negative if other column meets some condition?

Tags: pandas

If I have several columns

```
Transaction Type    Amount
debit               1
credit              1
```

How do I iterate through columns such that the Amount becomes negative if the Transaction Type is debit?

```
Transaction Type    Amount
debit               -1
credit              1
```

Comment: Thanks all, this was taking me forever to do. All the answers were good, I just had to pick one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['TransactionType']=='debit','Amount']=-df.Amount
df
Out[376]: 
  TransactionType  Amount
0           debit      -1
1          credit       1
```

Answer (score 3):

`(-1) ** True` gives us `-1`, `(-1) ** False` gives us `1`:

```
In [105]: df.Amount *= (-1) ** (df['Transaction Type'].eq('debit'))

In [106]: df
Out[106]:
  Transaction Type  Amount
0            debit      -1
1           credit       1
```

Comment: this answer makes me wish SO had multiple upvote options (like on codewars for ex) for best practice / smart / ...

Answer (score 2):

You want 
`df.Amount[df['Transaction Type']=='debit'] = - df.Amount`